# Loop and append/write to the same file without overwriting

Tags: shell, loops

```
for num in {1..5}
do
perl simulate.pl file.txt file2.txt > output.txt
done
```

But my output is overwritten every time. I know their should be some kind of a simple answer to this which I don't know.

Comment: `>` - operator - overwrite. `>>`- operator - append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `>>` to concat the contents into a file. `>` will overwrite the file every time you write into it.

Comment: Using `>>` on each write puts the output of multiple runs together into the same file, *and* is unnecessarily inefficient, since it re-opens the output file every time the `perl` command is run, rather than leaving the output file open for the entire duration of the loop.

Answer (score 7):

Either append at each iteration, or overwrite at the end.

```
> output.txt
for num in {1..5}
do
  perl simulate.pl file.txt file2.txt >> output.txt
done
```

​

```
for num in {1..5}
do
  perl simulate.pl file.txt file2.txt
done > output.txt
```

Comment: The one-big-redirection approach is the better one (avoiding re-opening the file over-and-over). Not as big a deal when doing something as heavy as `perl`, but a lot of the time folks are using this in ways that look like `echo "Starting run..." >>log`; in that scenario, the time needed to set up the redirection is actually substantial relative to the time needed for the `echo` as a whole.